# python top N word count, why multiprocess slower then single process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm doing a frequency word count using python, the single process version:

```
#coding=utf-8
import string
import time
from collections import Counter
starttime = time.clock()
origin = open("document.txt", 'r').read().lower()
for_split = [',','\n','\t','\'','.','\"','!','?','-', '~']

#the words below will be ignoered when counting
ignored = ['the', 'and', 'i', 'to', 'of', 'a', 'in', 'was', 'that', 'had',
       'he', 'you', 'his','my', 'it', 'as', 'with', 'her', 'for', 'on']
i=0
for ch in for_split:
    origin = string.replace(origin, ch, ' ')
words = string.split(origin)
result = Counter(words).most_common(40)
for word, frequency in result:
    if not word in ignored and i < 10:
        print "%s : %d" % (word, frequency)
        i = i+1
print time.clock() - starttime
```

then the multiprocessing version looks like:

```
#coding=utf-8
import time
import multiprocessing
from collections import Counter
for_split = [',','\n','\t','\'','.','\"','!','?','-', '~']
ignored = ['the', 'and', 'i', 'to', 'of', 'a', 'in', 'was', 'that', 'had',
       'he', 'you', 'his','my', 'it', 'as', 'with', 'her', 'for', 'on']
result_list = []

def worker(substr):
    result = Counter(substr)
    return result

def log_result(result):
    result_list.append(result)

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
    origin = open("document.txt", 'r').read().lower()
 for ch in for_split:
         origin = origin.replace(ch, ' ')
    words = origin.split()
    step = len(words)/4
        substrs = [words[pos : pos+step] for pos in range(0, len(words), step)]
    result = Counter()
    for substr in substrs:
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(substr,), callback = log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    result = Counter()
    for item in result_list:
        result = result + item
    result = result.most_common(40)
    i=0
    for word, frequency in result:
        if not word in ignored and i < 10:
            print "%s : %d" % (word, frequency)
            i = i+1

if __name__ == "__main__":
        starttime = time.clock()
        main()
        print time.clock() - starttime
```

the "document.txt" is about 22M, my laptop has to cores, 2G memory, the result of first version is 3.27s, and the second one is 8.15s, I've changed num of processes(**pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)**), from 2 to 10, the results remain almost the same, why is that, how can I make this program run faser than the single process version?

Comment: I found in testing a 1Mb file that a counter using `defaultdict` was faster than `Counter`, even the compiled `Counter` in `Python3.2`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343472/efficient-way-to-count-the-element-in-a-dictionary-in-python-using-a-loop/18349337#18349337

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's the overhead associated with distributing the individual strings to the workers and receiving the results. If I run your parallel code as given above with an example document (Dostojevski's "Crime and Punishment") it takes about 0.32 s to run, whereas the single-process version takes just 0.09 s. If I modify the `worker` function to just process the string "test" instead of the real document (still passing in the real string as an argument), the runtime goes down to 0.22 s. However, if I pass in "test" as argument to the `map_async` function, the runtime decreases to 0.06 s. Hence I'd say that in your case the runtime of the program is limited by the inter-process communication overhead.

With the following code I get the runtime of the parallel version down to 0.08 s: First, I partition the file into a number of chunks with (almost) equal length, making sure that the boundary between individual chunks does coincide with a newline. Then, I simply pass in the length and offsets of the chunks to each worker process, let it open the file, read the chunk, process it and return the results. This seems to cause significantly less overhead than directly distributing the strings through the map_async function. For larger file sizes you should be able to see an improvement in the runtime using this code. Also, if you can tolerate small count errors, you can omit the step to determine correct chunk boundaries and just split the file into equally large chunks. In my example, this brings down the runtime to 0.04 s, making the mp code faster than the single-process one.

```
#coding=utf-8
import time
import multiprocessing
import string
from collections import Counter
import os
for_split = [',','\n','\t','\'','.','\"','!','?','-', '~']
ignored = ['the', 'and', 'i', 'to', 'of', 'a', 'in', 'was', 'that', 'had',
       'he', 'you', 'his','my', 'it', 'as', 'with', 'her', 'for', 'on']
result_list = []

def worker(offset,length,filename):
    origin = open(filename, 'r')
    origin.seek(offset)
    content = origin.read(length).lower()

    for ch in for_split:
         content = content.replace(ch, ' ')

    words = string.split(content)
    result = Counter(words)
    origin.close()
    return result

def log_result(result):
    result_list.append(result)

def main():
    processes = 5
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=processes)
    filename = "document.txt"
    file_size = os.stat(filename)[6]
    chunks = []
    origin = open(filename, 'r')
    while True:
        lines = origin.readlines(file_size/processes)
        if not lines:
            break
        chunks.append("\n".join(lines))

    lengths = [len(chunk) for chunk in chunks]
    offset = 0

    for length in lengths:
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(offset,length,filename,), callback = log_result)
        offset += length

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    result = Counter()
    for item in result_list:
        result = result + item
    result = result.most_common(40)
    i=0
    for word, frequency in result:
        if not word in ignored and i < 10:
            print "%s : %d" % (word, frequency)
            i = i+1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    starttime = time.clock()
    main()
    print time.clock() - starttime
```

Comment: I have another question, I put your code on a machine which has 16 cores and 24G memory, and change the processes from two to 10, but the executing time become slower, why is that?

Comment: As before, I'd say that the time required for reading the files is getting large in comparison to the rest of the program. Maybe it will help to split the file beforehand and create several smaller files that can be read independently by each process without performing a seek, but with a large number of processes reading from disk you always risk to be bound by the I/O speed of your disk (memory & CPU time should not be the bottleneck here).

Comment: Thanks, and there is a little bug when I run the test file, maybe it caused by lines = origin.readlines(file_size/processes), this line has a risk to split a word, Is there a method to read several lines one time?

Comment: In principle, readlines should always read in entire lines, the sizehint only sets the approximate length in bytes to be read. See here for more information: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm

Comment: nzomkxia - are you worried about long words that are split at the end of a line?  By replacing '-' with ' ' I don't think your original code handles those any better.  It should be easy to check your text to see whether this is ever a problem.  I expect to find it in unprocessed scans of old print material, where the hyphen was used when right justifying text.