# efficient way to count the element in a dictionary in Python using a loop

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, coding-style

I have a list of values. I wish to count during a loop the number of element for each class (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5)

```
mylist = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,5]
mydict = dict()
for index in mylist:
    mydict[index] = +1
mydict
Out[344]: {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}
```

I wish to get this result

```
Out[344]: {1: 6, 2: 5, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 4}
```

Comment: `collections.Counter`, in your code you need: `mydict[index] += 1`

Comment: Could i ask an example, please? thanks in advance

Comment: `collections.Counter(mylist)` and you're done. (Well, aside from importing `collections`, and you still need to do whatever you were going to do with the counts, but `collections.Counter(mylist)` is the entire "counting things" phase.)

Comment: Although it is not the best way of doing it, your code would work if you changed `mydict[index] = +1` to `mydict[index] += 1`, and changed your dict to a defaultdict or initialized the values.

Comment: Perhaps [this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18318901/1679863)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary but `mydict[index] += 1` should not correct as initially no value there, it should be an exception ??

Comment: the way you are doing it is fine.  you just have a typo.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes you're right, I just wanted to point out that OP was using the operator incorrectly.(Though it'd raise `KeyError`.)

Comment: In addition to correcting the sequence of plus and assignment, just this modification would be necessary: `mydict = defaultdict(int)` to avoid exception on first access of each element.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For your smaller example, with a limited diversity of elements, you can use a set and a dict comprehension:

```
>>> mylist = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,5]
>>> {k:mylist.count(k) for k in set(mylist)}
{1: 6, 2: 5, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 4}
```

To break it down, `set(mylist)` uniquifies the list and makes it more compact:

```
>>> set(mylist)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Then the dictionary comprehension steps through the unique values and sets the count from the list.

This also is *significantly* faster than using Counter and faster than using setdefault:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict
import random

mylist=[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,5]*10

def s1(mylist):
    return {k:mylist.count(k) for k in set(mylist)}

def s2(mlist):
    return Counter(mylist)

def s3(mylist):
    mydict=dict()
    for index in mylist:
        mydict[index] = mydict.setdefault(index, 0) + 1
    return mydict   

def s4(mylist):
    mydict={}.fromkeys(mylist,0)
    for k in mydict:
        mydict[k]=mylist.count(k)    
    return mydict    

def s5(mylist):
    mydict={}
    for k in mylist:
        mydict[k]=mydict.get(k,0)+1
    return mydict     

def s6(mylist):
    mydict=defaultdict(int)
    for i in mylist:
        mydict[i] += 1
    return mydict       

def s7(mylist):
    mydict={}.fromkeys(mylist,0)
    for e in mylist:
        mydict[e]+=1    
    return mydict    

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    import timeit 
    n=1000000
    print(timeit.timeit("s1(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s1, mylist",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("s2(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s2, mylist, Counter",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("s3(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s3, mylist",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("s4(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s4, mylist",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("s5(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s5, mylist",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("s6(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s6, mylist, defaultdict",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("s7(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s7, mylist",number=n))
```

On my machine that prints  (Python 3):

```
18.123854104997008          # set and dict comprehension 
78.54796334600542           # Counter 
33.98185228800867           # setdefault 
19.0563529439969            # fromkeys / count 
34.54294775899325           # dict.get 
21.134678319009254          # defaultdict 
22.760544238000875          # fromkeys / loop
```

For Larger lists, like 10 million integers, with more diverse elements (1,500 random ints), use defaultdict or fromkeys in a loop:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict
import random

mylist = [random.randint(0,1500) for _ in range(10000000)]

def s1(mylist):
    return {k:mylist.count(k) for k in set(mylist)}

def s2(mlist):
    return Counter(mylist)

def s3(mylist):
    mydict=dict()
    for index in mylist:
        mydict[index] = mydict.setdefault(index, 0) + 1
    return mydict   

def s4(mylist):
    mydict={}.fromkeys(mylist,0)
    for k in mydict:
        mydict[k]=mylist.count(k)    
    return mydict    

def s5(mylist):
    mydict={}
    for k in mylist:
        mydict[k]=mydict.get(k,0)+1
    return mydict     

def s6(mylist):
    mydict=defaultdict(int)
    for i in mylist:
        mydict[i] += 1
    return mydict       

def s7(mylist):
    mydict={}.fromkeys(mylist,0)
    for e in mylist:
        mydict[e]+=1    
    return mydict    

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    import timeit 
    n=1
    print(timeit.timeit("s1(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s1, mylist",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("s2(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s2, mylist, Counter",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("s3(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s3, mylist",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("s4(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s4, mylist",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("s5(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s5, mylist",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("s6(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s6, mylist, defaultdict",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("s7(mylist)", setup="from __main__ import s7, mylist",number=n))
```

Prints:

```
2825.2697427899984              # set and dict comprehension 
42.607481333994656              # Counter 
22.77713537499949               # setdefault 
2853.11187016801                # fromkeys / count 
23.241977066005347              # dict.get 
15.023175164998975              # defaultdict 
18.28165417900891               # fromkeys / loop
```

You can see that solutions that relay on `count` with a moderate number of times through the large list will suffer badly/catastrophically in comparison to other solutions.

Comment: Does anyone know why the Cunter class is much slower than the default dict class?

Answer (score 6):

Try `collections.Counter`:

```
   >>> from collections import Counter
   >>> Counter([1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,5])
   Counter({1: 6, 2: 5, 5: 4, 3: 3, 4: 1})
```

In your code you can basically replace `mydict` with a `Counter` and write

```
mydict[index] += 1
```

instead of

```
mydict[index] = +1
```

Comment: Thanks but i am sorry because i need to find a way inside the loop. The list was an example because i have 32 GB of data to run in a loop/

Comment: If you have an iterator over your 32 GB of items, `collections.Counter` works the same with that as with a list.

Answer (score 4):

To rectify code:

```
mydict[index] = +1
```

should be:

```
mydict[index] = mydict.setdefault(index, 0) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks. with your example i got {1: 7, 2: 6, 3: 4, 4: 2, 5: 5}. The best way is mydict[index] = mydict.get(index, 0) + 1

Comment: @Gianni Oh I just corrected, I am new Python learner so I posted a simple answer.

Comment: I'd say the best way is a Counter myself, due to simplicity, but this way works.

Comment: @user2387370 If this works I will be happy as I am just started Python :)

Comment: Hey @Gianni did you notice your expression `mydict[index] = +1` is just `mydict[index] = 1` so you always get `1` in value :). You might misspelled by `mydict[index] += 1` but I suspect it would be a keyException as initially there is no value at `mydict[index]` read Ashwini's second comment to me in your question.

Answer (score 4):

A variation on the `setdefault` approach is the `collections.defaultdict`.  This is a bit faster.

```
def foo(mylist):
    d=defaultdict(int)
    for i in mylist:
        d[i] += 1
    return d
```

`itertools.groupBy` provides another option.  It's speed is about the same as `Counter` (at least on 2.7)

```
{x[0]:len(list(x[1])) for x in itertools.groupby(sorted(mylist))}
```

However time tests on this small test list might not be the same when dealing the 32Gb of data that the OP mentions in a comment.

---

I ran several of these options in the word count case in [python top N word count, why multiprocess slower then single process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300785/python-top-n-word-count-why-multiprocess-slower-then-single-process/1830095)

There the OP used Counter, and was trying to speed things up by using multiprocessing.   With a 1.2Mb text file, the counter using `defaultdict` was fast, take 0.2sec.  Sorting the output to get the top 40 words took as long as the counting itself.

`Counter` was a bit slower on `3.2`, and much slower on `2.7`.  That's because `3.2` a compiled version (`.so` file).

But the counter using `mylist.count` ground to a standstill when processing a large list; almost 200 sec.  It has to search that large list many times, once to collect keys, and then once for each key when it counts.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is assigning 1 as the value for each key. Replace `mydict[index] = +1` with `mylist.count(index)`

This should work:

```
mylist = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,5]
mydict = dict()
for index in mylist:
    mydict[index] = mylist.count(index)
mydict
```